# WPF: Why is callback function not called with binding mode OneWay?

Tags: wpf, binding, notifications, custom-controls

I have create a custom control with some properties, all seems to work as excepted.

But after some tests, I found a strange behavior which I don't understand. When I bind the property in `OneWay` mode, the callback of the property is not called... at least the property is not updated.

My property is defined as follow:

```
public uint ActiveLeds
{
   get { return (uint)GetValue(ActiveLedsProperty); }
   set { SetValue(ActiveLedsProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty ActiveLedsProperty =
   DependencyProperty.Register(
       nameof(ActiveLeds),
       typeof(uint),
       typeof(LedControl),
       new FrameworkPropertyMetadata
       {
           DefaultValue = 0u,
           PropertyChangedCallback = new PropertyChangedCallback(ActiveLedsChanged),
           DefaultUpdateSourceTrigger = System.Windows.Data.UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged,
           BindsTwoWayByDefault = true
       });
private static void ActiveLedsChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
   var c = d as LedControl;
   c.ActiveLeds = (uint)e.NewValue;
   c.UpdateLeds();
}
```

Binding is also really common, and works:

```
<local:LedControl  ActiveLeds="{Binding LedsOn}" />
```

But if I change the binding to OneWay, the callback function `ActiveLedsChanged` in my custom control is not called anymore.

```
<local:LedControl  ActiveLeds="{Binding LedsOn, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

Is this normal or did I do something wrong?

**Note**: `LedsOn` is a property from a class which implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you assign a new so-called [local value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/properties/dependency-property-value-precedence?view=netdesktop-8.0) to a dependency property that is currently bound OneWay, the Binding is removed. This does not happen when the Binding is TwoWay.

You are assigning a new local value in the PropertyChangedCallback:

```
private static void ActiveLedsChanged(
    DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var c = d as LedControl;
    c.ActiveLeds = (uint)e.NewValue; // here
    c.UpdateLeds();
}
```

The assignment is redundant, because the property does already have the assigned value. Change the callback method like shown below.

Also note that you should use an explicit cast instead of the `as` operator. When using `as`, you must check the result for null. Otherwise you get a NullReferenceException instead of a more appropriate InvalidCastException.

```
private static void ActiveLedsChanged(
    DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ((LedControl)d).UpdateLeds();
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Clements for your quick answer. 
Yes code could be optimized, but that is not really my problem.

What I don't understand, is why the callback is not called when the binding is `OneWay`, it is not possible to bind readonly properties to a custom control and by notified about there changes?

Comment: sorry to spam you but I am not so familiar with stackoverflow and my comment was send to early:
What I don't understand, is why the callback is not called when the binding is OneWay, it is not possible to bind readonly properties to a custom control and by notified about there changes?

Comment: It is explained in the answer. The callback is called once, then the redundant assignment replaces the Binding, and the property is never updated again.

Comment: my bad. I read to quickly your answer and I apologies about this. Now it make sense to me and most important **it works!**